# How to pass d, i arguments to on("click") function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

```
<body>
    <script src="d3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <button type="button" id="changeButton" onClick="hide(this)">Hide</button><br>
    <object data="MineralPorn.svg" id="myGraph">graph</object>
    <script>
        function getGraph() {
            return d3.select(document.getElementById("myGraph").contentDocument);
        }

        function nodeOnClick(d, i) {
            console.log(d.attr("class"));
        }

        function setup() {
            getGraph().select("#nodes")
                      .selectAll("circle")
                      .on("click", function(d, i) {nodeOnClick(d, i);} );
            console.log(getGraph().selectAll("#nodes").selectAll("circle"));
        }

        state="visible";
        function hide(button) {
            setup();
            var textElements = getGraph().selectAll("text");
            if (state=="visible") { value="none"; state="invisible"; }
            else { value=""; state="visible"; }

            button.firstChild.data = state=="visible" ? "Hide" : "Unhide";
            textElements.style("display",value);
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

The svg file is [here](https://gist.github.com/Skyyrunner/cc6c7c70adc388c9dceb#file-graphdata-svg). The basic structure of the svg is:

```
<svg>
    <g id="edges"></g>
    ....
    <g id="nodes">
        <circle class="thing1"/>
        <circle class="thing2"/>
        ....
        </g>
</svg>
```

Expected behavior: Upon clicking the Hide button, the text written on the nodes disappears, and the function nodeOnClick is linked to each circle in the SVG. Upon clicking any circle, its class is printed to the console.

Observed behavior: Instead of printing the class, the Javascript error `TypeError: d is undefined` is printed to the console.

The documentation lead me to believe that d and i are passed as arguments to the callback function, but it seems they aren't...? How would I properly link the onClick function to the SVG circles? Is my assumption that "d" is a d3.selection correct?

Comment: is your d3.js in the same directory as the html file?

Comment: In `nodeOnClick`, change `d` to `d3.select(this)`.

Comment: **"Is my assumption that "d" is a d3.selection correct?"** No, it isn't, `d` in that context is a data object that has been linked to the element with previous d3 code.  You never link data, so `d` is undefined.  As Lars points out, the element itself is accessible in your event handler as `this` and can be turned into a selection with `d3.select(this)` if you want to manipulate it.  You might want to work through [the tutorials](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials) before trying to figure out the API documentation.